# Reference request for stochastic process and applications

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I am looking for a text book that will cover the following topics I hope someone could suggest me a good text book that will provide me a good guidance regarding the following;

Generating functions, Convolution, Compounding, Random walks, Recurrent events, Discrete parameter Markov Chains, Continuous parameter Markov Chains, Birth and Death processes, Queuing processes.

I have no idea of stochastic processes yet so any book with good explanations will be very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ross's *Stochastic Processes* covers many of these topics.

Answer (score 1):

Feller's *An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications, Vol. I* is a classic that is still very useful. However, it covers a lot of ground, so it may not be the best choice if you want to learn the basics quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The following book interestingly covers topics that you were looking for:

Probability and Random Processes,  Geoffrey R. Grimmett, David R. Stirzaker

If you are looking for a book with a more applied approach:

Stochastic Processes: Theory for Applications, Robert Gallager

Comment: Thanks! Found a pdf for the 1st text will go through

Answer (score 1):

Karlin and Taylor's *A First Course in Stochastic Processes* and *A Second Course in Stochastic Processes* are very good, though quite expensive.

Comment: Hopefully an Indian subcontinent version will be available for a cheaper price!